# ContainsKey return unexpected result C# this is super strange needs advice

Tags: c#, dictionary, key

I have a

```
Dictionary<NodePair, string> repo;
```

I have implemented the

```
GetHashCode(), Equals()
```

on the

```
NodePair
```

When I try to search for a key using

```
if(Repo.ContainsKey(new NodePair(OneTree.Root, AnotherTree.Root)))
```

it return false, however, when I do

```
foreach (NodePair pair in Repo.Keys)
   if (pair.Equals(new NodePair(OneTree.Root, AnotherTree.Root)))
        Console.WriteLine();
```

The debugger stops at the

```
Console.WriteLine()
```

same thing happened when I do

```
foreach (NodePair pair in Repo.Keys)
   if (pair.GetHashCode() == (new NodePair(OneTree.Root, AnotherTree.Root)).GetHashCode())
        Console.WriteLine();
```

So why the hack that ContainsKey() return false?????????

Edit put everything together:

```
 foreach (NodePair pair in Repo.Keys)
    if (pair.Equals(new NodePair(OneTree.Root, AnotherTree.Root)))
         Console.WriteLine();

 foreach (NodePair pair in Repo.Keys)
    if (pair.GetHashCode() == (new NodePair(OneTree.Root, AnotherTree.Root)).GetHashCode())
         Console.WriteLine();

 if (Repo.ContainsKey(new NodePair(OneTree.Root, AnotherTree.Root)))
      Console.WriteLine();
```

The first two `Console.WriteLine()` hit and last one did not. Anyone can explain?

Comment: Please show complete  [MCVE] (in particular Equals, GetHashCode, and how you fill out dictionary). Most likely your type is mutable and you filled out your dictionary with the same key.

Comment: Side note: obviously you do know how to look at the source of the [ContainsKey](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,22fd7cd7408aed6e) in Microsoft Reference Source, so you may want to [edit] title to clarify what type of help you are looking for.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, if I filled out the dictionary with the same key then it does not ContainsKey()?

Comment: Do you implement `IEquatable<T>` on `NodePair`? If not, `ContainsKey` is probably trying to generate a hashcode via reflection.

Comment: @AustinDrenski: Not if `GetHashCode()` has been overridden. But really, we need to see a [mcve]... (It doesn't help that we don't even know if `NodePair` is a struct or a class...)

Answer (score 2):

It is implemented like:

```
private int FindEntry(TKey key)
{
    if (key == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
    }

    if (buckets != null)
    {
        int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
        for (int i = buckets[hashCode % buckets.Length]; i >= 0; i = entries[i].next)
        {
            if (entries[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(entries[i].key, key)) return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

You can see the full source code for [Dictionary](http://[this][1]) if you want because it is available online. If you want to debug it, please see [how to debug .NET code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx).

Comment: @user1935724 Please see [How do debug .NET Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx)